# Discord.JS - Hypixel Discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, minecraft

Can someone EXPLAIN to me on how to make a hypixel bot to give them a role and change there nickname based off what rank they are and there minecraft name

Example: If i type !verify (Myusername) and im Mvp+ there nickname will change to Mvp+(MyMinecraftname) instead of just my discord username

Just explain to me in detail on how to do it cause i wanna learn

Comment: StackOverflow is not a tutorial site.

Comment: It looks like hypixel has an api. https://api.hypixel.net/#tag/Player-Data Read through it and see if you can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [Hypixel API](https://api.hypixel.net/).

Then, you can use the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) npm package to call the API.
Follow the authentication part of the API website.

You will need to use the [PlayerData](https://api.hypixel.net/#tag/Player-Data) endpoint.

```js
const request = require('request');

request('https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=YOUR_API_KEY&name=MinecraftUsername', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  console.log(body.player.rank); //Get the rank. ex: MVP
});
```